# Regex Replace 2 values in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

If I have a `RichTextBox_1` that look like this:

```
TEXT  TEXT  444.444 555.555 270
TEXT  TEXT  444.444 555.555 270
TEXT  TEXT  444.444 555.555 270
```

And I would like to replace the values in the third column with values in a `RichTextBox_2`:

```
123.456
12.345
-123.987
```

And the values in the fourth column with values in a `RichTextBox_3`:

```
-9.876
98.76
-987.654
```

To get a final file:

```
TEXT  TEXT  123.456 9.876 270
TEXT  TEXT  12.345 98.76 270
TEXT  TEXT  -123.987 -987.654 270
```

How could I do this using **REGEX**?

---

***EDIT:***

### CODE:

*(Splits the values from a ListBox into: `RichTextBox_2` and `RichTextBox_3`. Instead of the ListBox I have moved everything in this to a `RichTextBox_1`)*

```
private void calculateXAndYPlacement()
{
 // Reads the lines in the file to format.
 var fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath + "\\Calculating X,Y File.txt");

  // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
  var fileList = new List<string>();
  // Adds each line in the file to the list.
 var fileLines = "";                                       #UPDATED @Corey Ogburn

 while ((fileLines = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)       #UPDATED @Corey Ogburn    
 fileList.Add(fileLines);                              #UPDATED @Corey Ogburn
 // Creates new lists to hold certain matches for each list.
 var xyResult = new List<string>();
 var xResult = new List<string>(); 
 var yResult = new List<string>();

 // Iterate over each line in the file and extract the x and y values
 fileList.ForEach(line =>
 {
     Match xyMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(?<y>-?\d+\.\d+)");

     if (xyMatch.Success)
     {
         // Grab the x and y values from the regular expression match
         String xValue = xyMatch.Groups["x"].Value;
         String yValue = xyMatch.Groups["y"].Value;

         // Add these two values, separated by a space, to the "xyResult" list.
         xyResult.Add(String.Join(" ", new[]{ xValue, yValue }));

         // Add the results to the lists.
         xResult.Add(xValue);
         yResult.Add(yValue);

         // Calculate the X & Y values (including the x & y displacements)
         double doubleX = double.Parse(xValue);
         double doubleXValue = double.Parse(xDisplacementTextBox.Text);
         StringBuilder sbX = new StringBuilder();
         sbX.AppendLine((doubleX + doubleXValue).ToString());
         double doubleY = double.Parse(yValue);
         double doubleYValue = double.Parse(yDisplacementTextBox.Text);
         StringBuilder sbY = new StringBuilder();
         sbY.AppendLine((doubleY + doubleYValue).ToString());
         calculatedXRichTextBox.AppendText(sbX + "\n");
         calculatedYRichTextBox.AppendText(sbY + "\n");
     }
  });
 }
```

---

I was trying to mess around with the Regex.Replace but I am having some trouble... Here is what I what trying and it does not work:

```
var combinedStringBuilders = new List<string>();
combinedStringBuilders.Add(String.Concat(sbX + "\t" + sbY));
var someNew = Regex.Replace(line, @"(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(?<y>-?\d+\.\d+)", combinedStringBuilders);
```

Comment: Why bother with regex, just split the line on spaces or tabs (whichever is appropriate), replace the 3rd and 4th elements, and put the line back together.

Comment: You should probably follow up on your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847696/c-replacing-values-mid-string) as well.

Comment: @Romanarmy: I think theNoobGuy is curious on what it would look like in REGEX and that is why he is asking?

Comment: Again, please people consider write WHY you downvote... he's asking a question and get downvote but don't even know why.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: This could be used in many situations. If a person wanted to find and replace multiple words with words in multiple files.. etc..To me it looks like he tried to follow up with that answer and never got a reply...

Comment: @R0MAN: I never got a reply from the previous guy on that post. But with that I will post what I wrote in that comment in an EDIT to the question above in a minute.

Comment: @theNoobGuy: As I said, you can accomplish this in a much easier manner without regex.  I added the answer to your other question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
            // Reads the lines in the file to format.
            var fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath + "\\Calculating X,Y File.txt");

            // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
            var fileList = new List<string>();

            // Adds each line in the file to the list.
            var fileLines = "";
            while ((fileLines = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                fileList.Add(fileLines);

            // Creates new lists to hold certain matches for each list.
            var xyResult = new List<string>();
            var xResult = new List<string>();
            var yResult = new List<string>();

            // Iterate over each line in the file and extract the x and y values
            fileList.ForEach(line =>
            {
                Match xyMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(?<y>-?\d+\.\d+)");
                if (xyMatch.Success)
                {
                    // Grab the x and y values from the regular expression match
                    String xValue = xyMatch.Groups["x"].Value;
                    String yValue = xyMatch.Groups["y"].Value;

                    // Add these two values, separated by a space, to the "xyResult" list.
                    xyResult.Add(String.Join(" ", new[] { xValue, yValue }));

                    // Add the results to the lists.
                    xResult.Add(xValue);
                    yResult.Add(yValue);

                    // Store the old X and Y values.
                    oldXRichTextBox.AppendText(xValue + Environment.NewLine);
                    oldYRichTextBox.AppendText(yValue + Environment.NewLine);
                    try
                    {
                        // Calculate the X & Y values (including the x & y displacements)
                        double doubleX = double.Parse(xValue);
                        double doubleXValue = double.Parse(xDisplacementTextBox.Text);
                        StringBuilder sbX = new StringBuilder();

                        sbX.AppendLine((doubleXValue - doubleX).ToString());

                        double doubleY = double.Parse(yValue);
                        double doubleYValue = double.Parse(yDisplacementTextBox.Text);
                        StringBuilder sbY = new StringBuilder();

                        sbY.AppendLine((doubleY + doubleYValue).ToString());

                        calculateXRichTextBox.AppendText(sbX + "");
                        calculateYRichTextBox.AppendText(sbY + "");

                        // Removes the blank lines.
                        calculateXRichTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(calculateXRichTextBox.Text, @"^\s*$(\n|\r|\r\n)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
                        calculateYRichTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(calculateYRichTextBox.Text, @"^\s*$(\n|\r|\r\n)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

General non-language specific method.
(I haven't done enough c# to write specific's)

5 (only) columns should be validated first.
This can be done by alternating non-whitespace
then whitespace.

regex:        `^(\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+)(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)(\s+\S+\s*)$`
replacemnt:   `${1}${sbX}${3}${sbY}${5}`

Open the 3 files. In a while loop, read a line from each file.
Validate both sbX/sbY that they have no whitespace.
Do the replacement, append the modified line to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply split your string into lines and then columns, I'm guessing your text has msdos line endings (cr+lf).

```
public string ReplaceColumn( string text, int col, List<string> newValues ){
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  var lines = Regex.Split( text, "[\r\n]+" ); // split into lines
  for ( int row = 0; row < lines.Count ; row++ ){
    var line = lines[row];
    var columns = Regex.Split( line, "[\s]+" ); // split into columns

    // replace the chosen column for this row
    columns[col] = newvalues[row];

    // rebuild the line and store it
    sb.Append( String.Join( " ", columns );
    sb.Append( "\r\n" ); // or whatever line ending you want

  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Of course, the above doesn't work too well if your text columns contain whitespace.